# List.Foreach() complains cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'

Tags: c#, .net-core

When I tried to run the following code, it tells me the 'cannot convert from 'void' to 'object' on the last line, does anyone know what is wrong with the code?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "asfdsanfdjsajfois";
    Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    s.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(a => {
        dict[a] = (dict.ContainsKey(a)) ? dict[a]+1 : 1;
    });
    pln(dict.Keys.ToList().ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(dict[a])));
}
```

Comment: There's no need to call `s.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach` when you can just call `s.ForEach`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Eh? `ForEach` is defined only on `List<T>`. Other `IEnumerable<T>`s don't have it. Plain `foreach` would work, but not what you suggested.

Comment: Oh that was really silly.....I put it in a pln method....hahahaha, thanks everyone

Comment: @hvd, ooops, meant `s.ToList().ForEach`.  A `String` is already an `IEnumerable(Of Char)` so there's no need for the `ToCharArray` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is clear without providing any more information:

`dict.Keys.ToList().ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(dict[a]))` is a statement that doesn't return anything `void`, and you're passing that to the `pln` function, that functions accepts and an argument of type `object`. You need to pass it an object for that type in order to make the compiler happy and for the code to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this part: `.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(dict[a])`; through this you are iterating through each keys in the Dictionary and print them to the console. Actually the `Console.WriteLine()` method's return type is `void` which means it is not returning anything. But you are trying to pass something to a method called `pln` But it is not specified in the question that how the method is defined or what's the value you are expected in that method.

Actually you need not to iterate through keys and then collect values, you can directly fetch values like this:

```
dict.Select(x=>x.Value).ToList()
```

If you need to pass each values to the plan method then you should modify the `pln` method signature like the following:

```
 private static void pln(int p)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(p);
    // Do something here
 }
```

And for this the query will be like `dict.ToList().ForEach(x => pln(x.Value));`

If you want to pass the values as List then the method signature will be :

```
private static void pln(List<int> p)
{
  // Do something here
}
```

And for this the query will be like `pln(dict.Select(a => a.Value).ToList());`